# how to upload data to google colab for shareable document

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to make a shareable document about medical imaging with various algorithms and so on. 
I know that I can use my google drive to upload the data there and every instance of colab to download it from there but this require authentication which make the document not so useful. How I can achieve that permanent storage in google colab without the need of any authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data can be public. You can share it publicly from google drive. Then, you can load the data without authentication with `gdown`

```
!gdown --id 0B7EVK8r0v71pZjFTYXZWM3FlRnM
```

Replace the ID with your image data's ID in Google Drive.

Comment: I don't know how to get file id. Can you tell me to be able to test your method

Comment: From Google Drive, you can share a file, using "Get shareable link". You will get something like https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7EVK8r0v71pZjFTYXZWM3FlRnM

Comment: @themean The id is that `0B7E...RnM` after `?id=` in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Files uploaded directly to Google Colab get deleted when the runtime is recycled. Easiest solution is to upload your data to a public Github repo, copy the URL for the file (the URL you get when clicking "raw"), and load the file in using your preferred method.

Comment: Can you give an example because my test with loading image didn't work